# how to setup a hadoop node to be a tasktracker but not a datanode

Tags: hadoop

For a special reason, I want to setup a hadoop node to be a tasktracker but not a datanode. It seems like there is a way to do it but I have not been able too. Could someone give me a hand?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup a host-exclude file for your namenode. 
This edit in the core-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.hosts.exclude</name>
  <value>YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_EXCLUDE_FILE</value>
</property>
```

This file is basically like a slave or master file. You have to just insert the hostname like:

```
host1
host2
```

When restarting the namenode will ignore these given hosts but the jobtracker will launch a tasktracker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did exactly what you said, but the datanode is still running in the excluded node. Do I need a special name for the exclude file. I have "exclude_dfs_hosts" and put in core-site.xml this ' <value>YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_EXCLUDE_FILE\exclude_dfs_hosts</value>'

Comment: Wierd, it is working now, wasn't in the first time. Thanks a lot. Some one should update the configuration manual :)

Comment: actually you have to replace the path that I wrote in capslock with your path. The file should be readable to the user which starts hadoop. But if it works now :) Fine!